# Controller-independent stepper functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-controller

I have an AngularJS project, and I'm using a modified version of md-steppers, whose interesting functions boil down to this:

```
var enableNextStep = function () {
            //do not exceed into max step
            if ($scope.selectedStep >= $scope.maxStep) {
                return;
            }
            //do not increment $scope.stepProgress when submitting from previously completed step
            if ($scope.selectedStep === $scope.stepProgress - 1) {
                $scope.stepProgress = $scope.stepProgress + 1;
            }
        };

        var completeCurrentStep = function (CurrentStep) {
            $scope.stepData[CurrentStep].completed = true;
        };

        $scope.moveToNextStep = function moveToNextStep() {
            if ($scope.selectedStep < $scope.maxStep) {
                enableNextStep();
                $scope.selectedStep = $scope.selectedStep + 1;
                completeCurrentStep($scope.selectedStep - 1); //Complete After changing Step
            }
        };

        $scope.moveToPreviousStep = function moveToPreviousStep() {
            if ($scope.selectedStep > 0) {
                $scope.selectedStep = $scope.selectedStep - 1;
            }
        };
```

The problem is that I would like to use these four functions in two different controllers (so as to not repeat them), that have different `stepProgress`, `selectedStep` and `maxStep` values. I couldn't find a way to do so with services, but I might just be confused about the way AngularJS work, as I am more used to Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting out that functionality into a factory that accepts an array of callbacks and a controller's `ng-model` would make it more reusable. Of course, ultimately the API you want is up to you. The goal is that you don't want any `$scope` business inside the factory, it shouldn't be concerned about what's inside the callbacks, it just steps through them.

```
/**
 * @param steps {array} - array of callbacks
 */

function stepperFactory(steps) {
  iterate(0, steps);
}

function iterate(current, steps) {
  if (!steps[current])
    return;
  if (typeof steps[current] === 'function')
    // pass an async "done" callback
    // so your array of input callbacks can be async
    // you could also use promises or $q for this
    steps[current](() => iterate(current + 1, steps));
}
```

And so the api you expose would be like:

```
['stepperFactory', function(stepperFactory) {
  this.model = { step: 0, msg: 'start' };
  this.steps = [
    (done) => {
      this.model.step++;
      done();
    },
    (done) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.model.msg = '3rd step';
        this.model.step++;
        done();
      });
    }
  ];
  stepperFactory(this.model, this.steps);
}]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you enlighten me on the purpose of these timeouts and `(done)` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use service to share functions which will take `maxStep`, `stepProgress`, etc as arguments and instead of modifying the `$scope`, they will return updated values.

In service:

```
function moveToPreviousStep(step) {
  if (step > 0) {
    return (step - 1);
  }
  return step;
};
```

and in controller

```
function moveToPreviousStep() {
  $scope.selectedStep = service.moveToPreviousStep($scope.selectedStep);
}
$scope.moveToPreviousStep = moveToPreviousStep;
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that alternative, but it is still not DRY enough, I might as well just stick with the current duplication.